# Keyword Searching Tool - Python (SQL ODBC Database)

Tags: python, sql, odbc

I want to build a tool in python that takes a word (or list) input from a user, connects to an ODBC database and then using SQL, pull off all those rows which has that word in it.

Does anyone have any suggestions of libraries I should be looking at to try and do this?

Comment: The pyodbc library will allow you to connect to an ODBC database if your system has an ODBC driver for that database.

Comment: Ok, great, ty. I will check it out!